# Type-safe way to reuse defensive copy method given immutable class hierarchy

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, immutability

I have a base class and a derived class, both designed to be **immutable** (ctor and getters omitted):

```java
public class PageQuery<T> {
    private final T queryFilter;
    private PageCond pageCond; // pagination parameter

    // E withPageCond(PageCond newPageCond) { 
    //    return a brand new copy of `this` with `pageCond` replaced with `newPageCond`
    //    that can be reused across class hierarchy
    // }
}

public class PageSortQuery<T> extends PageQuery<T>{
    private final SortCond sortCond; // sorting parameter
}
```

How to add a method that returns defensive copy of `this` to the base class so that all classes in this hierarchy can benefit from it? Is there a way to accomplish it without `clone()`?

Comment: Can you define your fields protected and access them from subclasses?

Comment: @Barracuda Maybe. But my goal is to make all classes further added to this hierarchy to benefit from `withPageCond` transparently with minimal effort. Adding code in every subclass is not a wise option as for my goal.

Comment: The Builder design pattern is a good potential replacement for your design. Here, `PageQuery<T>` cannot foresee how it will be derived, so it cannot control the instantiation of objects from non-existent subclasses.

Comment: @CedricSun, in what sense do you want other subclasses to benefit from it? Is there any problem with defining copy method in the superclass that returns a copy of the immutable instance and override this method in subclasses, since they have access to the field of their superclass through getter methods?

Comment: @Barracuda Subclasses shouldn't even be aware of the presence of `PageCond` field. All they know is an inherited method `withPageCond`, calling which will return a copy of `this` (with consistent type - the calling subclass's type). No need to override anything.

Comment: @CedricSun, shouldn't mean that you don't have getters of pageCond field? If there are getters, they are already aware of this field.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you mean something like this, in this case if you call the withFilter method the origin would not become changed.

```
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Query <T> {
  @Getter
  private final String name;
  @Getter
  private final Predicate<T> filter;

  public Query<T> withFilter(Predicate<T> filter){
    return new DelegatingQuery<T>(this){
      @Override
      public Predicate<T> getFilter() {
        return Query.this.filter;
      }
    };
  }

  static class DelegatingQuery<T> extends Query<T>{
    @Delegate
    private final Query<T> query;

    public DelegatingQuery(Query<T> query) {
      super(query.name,query.filter);
      this.query = query;
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: I like how this kept `filter` final, but the point is to have one or more subclass adding business fields to the base `Query` and share the same `withXXX()` method (in a type-safe way)

Comment: You want that the withXXX() method returns an instance of the subclass?

Comment: Yes. I'm thinking about CRTP like the `java.lang.Enum`, so that base class can refer to the type of its subclass. But that would introduce 3-level inheritance since there has to be an abstract base class, and CRTP with multi-level (more than 2) inheritance is always a problem (possible, but lots of effort there)... let alone the maintenance cost. Also I can't avoid `clone` so far.